# What is the meaning of the statement below?

Tags: c++

I was going through C++ primer, and I am confused in line 2

```
const int ci = 42;    // we cannot change ci; const is top-leve

int i = ci;           // ok: when we copy ci, its top-level const is ignore
```

As per me, we defined ci to be constant. Then we simply copy it in 'i'

1. How does the "top-level const is ignored" come into the picture?
2. Can someone explain what exactly is difference between top & low-level const?

Comment: `const` means the compiler won't let you change `ci`'s value.  You're still free to read `ci`'s value, however, which is what you are doing when you assign `i = ci`

Comment: The term `const  is top-level` has no meaning. The variable is `const` or is not. The term `top-level const is ignore` has no meaning to me. If something is `const` you can still read its value (as that does not change its value).

Answer (score 4):

The value stored in the variable defined as `const int ci` remains a constant for its entire lifetime.  This means you could not change its value in future lines of code.  (ie. You could not later write `ci = 43;`, the compiler would enforce the `const` and not allow this code to build.)

However, when copied its value to `int i`, you created a new variable named `i`.  And `i` was not defined as `const`, so it is what we refer to as *mutable*, meaning the code that follows can change its value.

Answer (score 3):

The **top-level** term *is used by some people and is dragged in from script languages*. I saw it used in some C++ primers in meaning that "object itself is const" while `const int* p` would be low-level const, i.e. referred object is const.

```
const int* p;   // low-level const, a pointer to a const 

int* const p = &i;   // top-level const, pointer is const
```

This term is not officially defined  and perhaps should avoided due to confusion it creates.

```
const int* const p = &ci; // top-level and low-level?
```

C++ by default creates and operates upon mutable data, so those terms have little value . If you initialize a non-const object with a const one, new copy is mutable unless this is a class type and there is an intentional code that does otherwise in user-defined constructor. Created object still will not be const unless declared so. Also C++ enjoys existence of `const_cast` conversion which would be an affront to languages like Clojure.